# OutOfMemoryError while downloading files using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, project-reactor, fileoutputstream

I occur an OutOfMemoryError while performing the async download of ~2k files (0,5MB each).
On my local machine, everything works fine but while doing that in a docker image it lacks memory. I don't want to bump my docker image memory allocation to the size of my local machine (although if it will be the only possible way I will do it).

To download each file I use such a method:

```
static void download(String fileUrl, File localFile) throws HttpException, CannotReadException, TagException,InvalidAudioFrameException, ExecutionException,InterruptedException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(localFile)
    AsyncHttpClient client = Dsl.asyncHttpClient()

    client.prepareGet(fileUrl)
            .execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<FileOutputStream>() {

                @Override
                AsyncHandler.State onStatusReceived(HttpResponseStatus responseStatus) throws Exception {
                    def status = responseStatus.getStatusCode()
                    if (status != 200) {
                        println(status + " file not downloaded: " + fileUrl)
                        return State.ABORT
                    }
                    return State.CONTINUE
                }

                @Override
                AsyncHandler.State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
                    stream.getChannel()
                            .write(bodyPart.getBodyByteBuffer())
                    return State.CONTINUE
                }

                @Override
                FileOutputStream onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {
                    return stream
                }
            })
            .get()

    stream.getChannel().close()
    client.close()
}
```

On each downloaded file, I perform some checks (also doing it in an async way) and collect results.

```
List filesThatMatchMyTest = Flux.fromIterable(items)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map { it ->
                def uri = it.URI
                File localFile = File.createTempFile("file-$uri", ".txt")
                String fileUrl = createFileLink(uri)
                download(fileUrl, localFile)
                return check(localFile, locale, fileUrl)
            }
            .sequential()
            .filter { !it.isBlank() }
            .collectList()
            .block()
```

I look for a solution that would help to deal with this issue inside the code.

Side note, the local machine has 16 GB of memory while docker image 2 GB

Comment: it's static method ?

Comment: I believe that this is related to the fact that java doesn't know what it's maximum allowed memory is because it's running in a container.  Check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources for how to make java use a certain amount of memory.

Comment: @Rajesh both `download()` and `check()` methods are static

Comment: I think you'll be using the `--memory="2G"` option.  I could be wrong.  (I'd probably go for less than 2g tbh)

Comment: @przemlat Can you download file in separate service instead of static method

Comment: Change the parallel stuff to do n files at a time, where n <= 100, instead of the whole load.  You don't actually gain anything after a while but you use a lot more memory if you try to parallel everything to save a few lines of code.

Comment: @DanRayson I have both `memory` and `memoryReservation` already set

Comment: You might get a bit more help if you use the `Docker` tag in your question.  With this being an OOM error, I'm pretty sure it's down to how java is interacting with your docker container.  For some more reading about java memory limits (as opposed to the docker limits I linked before) check out https://nodramadevops.com/2019/10/docker-memory-resource-limits/  Notice that the `java -jar` command also has many memory related options.

Comment: @John I followed your idea and it helped. I see quite a big drop in performance speed, but as it is a test not even performed in a build process I can live with that until I'll think of a better solution

Comment: How can you see a drop in performance when it wasn't even working before?  You cannot compare it working on your PC vs within Docker.  If you ran both on your PC and you see a drop in perf, I suspect there's something wrong with your implementation rather than the strategy.